# D3.js v5 loading behavior is different from v3 in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I wish to use d3 and Jupyter together. I can load and use v3 of d3 but v5 appears to load successfully but is not then accessible.

```
    %%html
    Hello
    <SVG HEIGHT=100 WIDTH=100></SVG>
```

```
    %%javascript
    if (typeof(d3) !== "undefined") { d3=undefined; }
    setTimeout(() => {
        $.getScript("https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js")
            .done(function (script, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                d3.selectAll("SVG").
                append("circle").
                attr("r",10).attr("cx",10).attr("cy",10).attr("fill","red")});
    }, 1000);
```

When executed Chrome shows the following error in the Javascript console

```
VM632:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectAll' of undefined
    at Object.eval (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:762), <anonymous>:6:16)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

The equivalent code bundled in an HTML file loads and works. Changing the d3 url to load v3 instead of v5 also works.

I've tried this on 2 different Windows 10 machines primarily on Chrome but with equivalent behavior on IE. FWIW I have tried clearing the browser caches.

I'm using Jupyter 5.7.4 with Python 3.7.1.

Is this broken or am I doing something wrong?